# What namespace is needed to use BigInteger in Windows Phone silvelight application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, silverlight-5.0

I want to use BigInteger in my Windows Phone silvelight application.
What namespace is needed to use it?
Why it is not supporting to `using System.Numerics;`
For BigInteger, my code is here:

```
BigInteger n = new BigInteger("19579160939939334264971282204525611731944172893619019759209712156289528980860378672033164235760825723282900348193871051950190013953658941960463089031452404364269503721476236241284015792700835264262839734314564696723261501877759107784604657504350348081273959965406686529089170062268136253938904906635532824296510859016002105655690559115059267476786307037941751235763572931501055146976797606538425089134251611194500570922973015579287289778637105402129208324300035518642730384616767241853993887666288072512402523498267733725021939287517009966986976768028023180137546958580922532786773172365428677544232641888174470601681", 10);
```

Comment: If System.Numerics doesn't support in Silverlight Windows Phone, thn how can I use BigInteger?

Comment: Have you referenced System.Numerics.dll?

Comment: What's the scenario that you're trying to fix? That seems an awfully long number to display on a tiny screen, after all.

Comment: Also, are you targeting Windows Phone 7.x, or just 8?

Comment: Can you leverage Mono's source code for their implementation of [BigInteger](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Numerics/System.Numerics/BigInteger.cs)?

Comment: no i have not referenced System.Numerics.dll? Should I? If yes,how? @Nick

Comment: Yes, I am targetting 7.1 @RowlandShaw

Answer (score 4):

You can try using the [Int128 library](http://int128.codeplex.com/) from CodePlex.

Answer (score 1):

C# PCL library for computations with big numbers such as Int128 and Int256.
https://github.com/Taggersoft/BigMath